# How to find substring sets which is not contained specific pattern using regular expression in python?

Tags: python, regex

Recently, I work using many text with some tags.
for example,

**[000000]I am a [FFFFFF]boy[-], and my name is [ABABAB][James][-]**

[~~~~~~] means head tag which defines color(RGB code) of text until tail tag, and [-] means tail tag which also means end point of the color. In example above, 'boy''s color is FFFFFF, and '[James]''s color is ABABAB.

all words are applied one or zero tag-pair at a time. However some head tags have no tail tag like [000000] in example text. (special case)

In this situation, I should find all text sets between tag-pair like 'boy' and '[James]' with its tag-pair.
To resolve it, I use python regex below,
(group1 : head tag, group2 : text within tag-pair, group3 : tail tag)

```
import re

p_general_tag = re.compile('(\[\S{6}\])(.+?)(\[\-\])')
text = "[000000]I am a [FFFFFF]boy[-], and my name is [ABABAB][James][-]"

matched_texts = p_general_tag.findall(text)

print(matched_texts)
```

it finds wrong result.

```
[('[000000]', 'I am a [FFFFFF]boy', '[-]'), ('[ABABAB]', '[James]', '[-]')]
```

In my opinion, if there are some [~~~~~~] patterns in group2, it should not be matched. However I don't know how to do.

Can you please help me?

Comment: Can you provide the expected result ? I'm not sure what is wrong in the actual result. Also, if you intend to have multiple layer, such as `[fff]Poem, [aaa] Line 1 : [f00]Roses[-] are [f00]red[-][-][bbb] Line 2 : [00f]Violets[-] are [00f]blue[-][-]`, you will probably have to iterate manually on the loop (or use regex that match "leaf" tag pair, and remove theses leafs to then match other layers etc...)

Comment: @MisterAqua expected result is :
[('[FFFFFF]', 'boy', '[-]'), ('[ABABAB]', '[James]', '[-]')]

Comment: @MisterAqua 
Except some special case, tail tag appears after its head-pair tag.
for example, 
head1 ~~ head2 ~~ tail2 ~~ tail1     <- this case is not existed.
head1 ~~ tail1 ~~ head2 ~~ head3 ~~ tail3 ~~    <- this case can be existed. in this case, head2 is special case and I don't need extract head2-part.

I hope this information is useful. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
(\[[^][\s]{6}])((?:(?!\[[^][\s]{6}]).)*)(\[-])
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/a1va0O/1).

*Details*:

- `(\[[^][\s]{6}])` - Group 1: `[`, then six chars other than `[`, `]` and whitespace and then a `]` char
- `((?:(?!\[[^][\s]{6}]).)*)` - Group 2: any char, other than a line break char, zero or more times but as many as possible, that does not start the "`[`, then six chars other than `[`, `]` and whitespace and then a `]` char" sequence
- `(\[-])` - Group 3: a `[-]` substring.

Comment: Awsome!! great answer! Thank yo so much :)